# Colab's mounting does not work at "/content/drive"

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have a Colab notebook that performs a computer vision project, which needs the data from the Google Drive to use upon. But for some reasons when I run 'drive.mount("/content/drive") I kept getting an error telling me that the mountpoint does not exist. May I wonder if there is a way to fix this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Would you please share the actual code and the exact error message (and if possible, a link to the Colab notebook as well) so we could reproduce the error? Also, I'd recommend checking out "[External data](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=RWSJpsyKqHjH)" docs, just to be sure that you have done everything correctly.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was actually able to resolve the error by resetting the variable of the root, as well as the running environment to factory-based initialization. Many thanks for your help! My apologies and I will provide complete information for my future questions.